# Where is it looking for the templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I keep getting `TemplateDoesNotExist`

```
vidPal_project/
├── manage.py
├── templates
│   ├── base.html
│   └── index.html <--- the one I want
├── vidPal_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── viddy
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── admin.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = '/templates/'
```

**vidPal_project/urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', 'viddy.views.home', name='home'),
```

**viddy/views.py**

```
def home(request):
    sent = 'hello'
    return render(request,'index.html', locals())
```

Where in the chain of things have I gone wrong?

Comment: Why have you overridden `TEMPLATE_DIRS` at all? The default setting would work fine with that layout.

Comment: I don't have a default setting. Using `Django version 1.6.2`

Comment: Yes of course you do. It's not included in the settings.py file created by Django precisely because you shouldn't need to change it.

Comment: Well, what's the default location then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TEMPLATE_DIRS` expects absolute paths, not relative ones. This can be a hassle when moving from dev to production if you don't have exactly the same setup, so here's a neat trick. In your `settings.py`:

```
import os.path
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
...

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates')
)
```

`PROJECT_DIR` will be set to the location of `settings.py`, so in your case you'll probably have to make it `os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, '../templates')`.

The same applies to other absolute locations in your projects, i.e:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static_root')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

etc.

Answer (score 3):

Substitute `TEMPLATE_DIRS = '/templates/'` with `TEMPLATE_DIRS = 'templates/'`. The first one is an absolute address (mind the `/` at the beginning) which looks for templates folder in the `root`, which is wrong. The second one is relative and will look in the current folder.
The best way is to build your path dynamically as described in Björns answer.

Comment: In the root of my whole file system?

Comment: So where does `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` look? It's there by default.